# android notify when startActivity intent has completed?

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to be able to tell when a spawned activity (via an intent) has completed, how would I do so?

This is what I have:

```
    alertDialog.setButton2("Text", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String uri = "smsto:" + "";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uri));
            intent.putExtra("sms_body", PASSWORD_GENERATOR
                    .generatePasswordForSeed(seedText, hourToUse));
            intent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);

            // -- open the text message activity
            startActivity(intent);

            // -- I need to reset the calling activity now, but AFTER the text message activity has completed. Right now the SMS closes right away as I have no wait in...
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
        }
    });
```

### **EDIT #1**

Per the suggestions below, I've made some modifications. Now, however, the launched SMS activity just "sits there" once the text is sent. I can't figure out how to get it to return to the calling activity. This is what I have:

```
alertDialog.setButton2("Text", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String uri = "smsto:" + "";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uri));
                intent.putExtra("sms_body", PASSWORD_GENERATOR
                        .generatePasswordForSeed(seedText, hourToUse));
                intent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);

                startActivityForResult(intent, Activity.RESULT_OK);

                registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        finish();
                        startActivity(getIntent());
                    }

                }, new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"));

                ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                Handler handler = new Handler();

                contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri
                        .parse("content://sms"), true, new ContentObserver(
                        handler) {

                    @Override
                    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                        finish();

                        return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                        super.onChange(selfChange);

                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
    }
```

Comment: hey, @javamonkey79- how this was ended up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Followup Answer for second question:**
Out of curiosity, have you considered sending the text without creating an activity? The reason I ask is because it seems, from what I can tell, no user experience is happening within your SMS activity. If you don't have views and user interactions then maybe just defining a thread or creating a helper class would do the job.

**Original Answer for first question:**
Try using startActivityForResult(Intent, int). Your current activity can get notified when the text message activity finishes.

Comment: You've been helpful, thank you. Although the the title suggests the simple solution (and hence one question), I believe the post itself shows that there is more going on, not so much multiple questions.

Comment: I believe I need to use an activity, I do want user interaction as I don't always know who the text message recipient will be.

Comment: I've started a 50pt bounty if you want to add a more complete answer. +1 nonetheless :)

Answer (score 12):

Use `startActivityForResult(intent, positiveinteger);`

Do what you want to do, in the started activity when you think activity has finished successfully, do `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);` `finish();`

And in the activity that started override `onActivityResult()` method. And test if your called activity finished it job.

Never ever ever ever use `Activity.RESULT_OK` for `requestCode`, because it is negative constant. And the Docs says that `onActivityResult()` method will be called for every positive integer `requestCode`:

Rewrite and follow this

How you start the activity for result:

```
      static final int STATIC_RESULT=2; //positive > 0 integer.
      Intent i = new Intent("my.activity.startNewOne");
      i.putExtra("category", category);
    startActivityForResult(i, STATIC_RESULT);
```

In your `startNewOne` activity you finish with result like:

```
    //after the job is done, use the method i mentioned in the comments to check if the sms is delivered/submitted. and proceed if true with this
    if(smsObject.getStatus()==0)//by the docs means successfuly sent
{
    Intent i = getIntent(); //get the intent that has been called, i.e you did called with startActivityForResult();
    i.putExtras(b);//put some data, in a bundle
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);  //now you can use Activity.RESULT_OK, its irrelevant whats the resultCode    
    finish(); //finish the startNewOne activity
}
```

How do you use `onActivityResult()` method:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

          if (requestCode == STATIC_RESULT) //check if the request code is the one you've sent
          {
                 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
                 {
                // this is successful mission, do with it.

                 {
                 } else
                         // the result code is different from the one you've finished with, do something else.
                     }
          }


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
```

Comment: How can you know when an SMS activity finished successfully then?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#getStatus() you check if the sms is sent successfully, if it sent, then you `setResult()` and then `finish()`. Dont forget the permissions :)

Comment: It doesn't seem you can tell when the sms activity is finished. You can tell when the text is sent, rec'd, etc. but there is no hook to the sms activity itself the way I've set it up in the code above. I'll edit to show what I mean.

Comment: I've started a 50pt bounty if you want to add a more complete answer. +1 nonetheless :)

Comment: My "startone" activity is Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, if I change this in my intent I won't be sending a sms anymore, right?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you will have to use `SmsManager`

Use this: [SMS Messaging in Android | mobiForge](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)

You can receive the `SMS_SENT`

***Note***:
Make sure you are restarting your calling activity using `onCreate()`

Comment: But I need to use the built in sms intent. The SmsManager lets me send text messages, but I want the user to use the built in sms app, not to just statically send a text on their behalf.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your new question, you can add `exit_on_sent` to the intent, which will cause the SMS activity to return after sending an invitation.

```
smsIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
```

Unfortunately, it looks like it still returns a `resultCode` of `Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED`, whether you do it this way or if they hit the back button, so you can't tell if the user has actually sent the text or not.